# Не могу вырезать теги из строки

Tags: php, xml, ms-word

Суть в том, что вытаскиваю текст из document.xml из word документа. Получаю строку с тегами.
Есть следующий кусок строки:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="6EA357F9" w14:textId="56718C92" w:rsidR="00EB1C12" w:rsidRPr="00D25518" w:rsidRDefault="004C2F3B" w:rsidP="004C2F3B">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="a3"/>
        <w:ind w:firstLine="0"/>
        <w:jc w:val="center"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
                <w:lang w:val="ru-RU"/>
            </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
             <w:rFonts w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
             <w:sz w:val="32"/>
             <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
             <w:lang w:val="ru-RU"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>АННОТАЦИЯ</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
</w:p>
```

Хочу заменить например `</w:t>` на `\n` `str_replace('</w:t>', "\n", $file);`, но ничего не выходит.
Хочу разбить следующей регуляркой `preg_match_all("#<w:t>(.*)</w:t>#", $file, $matches);` на блоки, примерно как в примере выше, но тоже ничего не выходит, `$matches` пустой.
Я что-то не так делаю? Может быть можно регулярку заменить чем-то проще? Желательно бы получить из всего document.xml массив, который будет разбит на блоки `<w:p> ... </w:p>`.
Кстати, пробовал через `simplexml_load_string`

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);

var_dump($xml->w:p);
```

но тоже ничего не выходит.
Пожалуйста, подскажите.

Comment: `var_dump($xml->w:p);` - и что, никакой ошибки на это PHP не выдаёт?

Comment: Да, ошибка. Я образно написал. Пробовал `$xml->w` тоже ошибка.
Ещё `simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found`. Походу не видит `<xml` вначале

**UPD** Мой косяк, немного не так делаю. На `$xml->w` выдаёт `object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) { }`

Answer (score 1):

Я попробовал и всё работает если у вас не работает скорее всего из за PHP:

```
<?php
$content = '<w:p w14:paraId="6EA357F9" w14:textId="56718C92" w:rsidR="00EB1C12" w:rsidRPr="00D25518" w:rsidRDefault="004C2F3B" w:rsidP="004C2F3B">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="a3"/>
        <w:ind w:firstLine="0"/>
        <w:jc w:val="center"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
                <w:lang w:val="ru-RU"/>
            </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
             <w:rFonts w:cs="Times New Roman"/>
             <w:sz w:val="32"/>
             <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
             <w:lang w:val="ru-RU"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>АННОТАЦИЯ</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
</w:p>';
$replace = str_replace('</w:p>', '\n', $content);
echo $replace;
?>
```